# SQLAlchemy: AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a many to many relation database with puzzles and categories. When I run it for the first time, everything works fabulously. All tables get created and filled with content. However, when I run it for a second time to further populate the database the following error pops up.
`AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column '_sa_instance_state'`

I've narrowed the issue down to knowing it crashes when there is a same category already found in the database. But that one can't be assigned to the new puzzle its categories, since that's where the crash happens.

I've made the following reproducible example. Run it once and it runs perfectly, run it again and it will crash.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///example.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

category_identifier = db.Table('category_identifier',
    db.Column('categories_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id')),
    db.Column('puzzles_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('puzzles.id'))
)

class Puzzle(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'puzzles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    categories = db.relationship("Category", secondary=category_identifier)


class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)


db.create_all()
db.session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    myList = ['cat1', 'cat2, cat3']
    puzzle = Puzzle()

    for cat in myList:
        category = db.session.query(Category.name).filter_by(name=cat).first()
        
        if not category:
            category = Category(name=cat)

        puzzle.categories.append(category)

    db.session.add(puzzle)
    db.session.commit()
```

**edit**

I found that the type of the variable is different in both cases and thought maybe that could be a reason for it to fail.
The first time, the type of the variable is `<class 'models.Category'>`and the second time, when it crashes, it's of the instance `<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>`.

Is there any way to typecast the variable to the class models.category and see if that might be a solution?

Comment: @snakecharmerb the thing is, I want to populate the database with multiple puzzles each with overlapping categories but not completely similar as to take the same object. This was just to make a minimal reproducible example that all categories of the puzzle are the same.

Comment: `category = db.session.query(Category.name).filter_by(name=cat).first()` should be `category = db.session.query(Category).filter_by(name=cat).first()`

Comment: @snakecharmerb wow, that's it! Many thanks! I've been staring myself dead at this issue not finding any information about this online. You saved my day!

Comment: What the error message is telling you is that you are trying to add something to the session that isn't an instance of `db.Model`.  `db.session.query(Category.name)...` will return `('cat1',)` - a row, not a model instance.  but it's tricky to spot, because the code "looks right" from a high level.

Comment: @snakecharmerb That's a great explanation, thanks! If you formulate it into an answer, I can accept it as the correct one for future stackoverflowers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message

> AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column '_sa_instance_state'

is rather obscure at first glance.  What it means is that we are trying to perform some operation which is specific to a model instance, but the thing that the operation is being performed on is not a model instance.

In this particular case, in executing

```py
session.add(puzzle)
```

we seem to be adding a `Puzzle` and its associated categories to the session, but the result of

```py
db.session.query(Category.name).filter_by(name=cat).first()
```

will be a row (like `('cat1',)`, because we are retrieving an attribute - `Category.name` - not a model instance.

Replacing the query with

```py
db.session.query(Category).filter_by(name=cat).first()
```

will retrieve a model instance and fix the problem.